# Possible to route audio directly from usb-audio line-in to same usb audio line-out?

Tags: usb, pi-3, alsa, audio-playback

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 - and was able to get my ASUS USB audio device to work both with mic/line-in and output to speakers.

Right now I can do it it in two steps:

- arecord will record to a wav file
- aplay will play the wav file

Just wondering if it's possible with a simple config setting to somehow have the audio pass thru directly from line-in to speaker-out?

Hoping to avoid using avconv or ffmepg to redirect -seems like a lot of cpu just to do pass-thru audio.

If I can do this, I'd like to be running a program in the background that would interrupt the audio for a message and then return back to passthru audio

Comment: Are both line-in and speaker-out part of the same device? If yes, what are its mixer controls (see `alsamixer`)?

Comment: Yes they are. Not sure what you mean - Input is set to Line, Loudness is on, PCM volumes are set to middle low levels. I have both input and output defaulting to the HW device 1 so I can pipe directly from arecord to aplay and it does work

Comment: So there is no "Line-In" playback control? Then you need to use software. (Any software. I've heard PulseAudio can do this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a simple solution using **just ALSA** and uses little CPU - around 3-5% on **RPi 3 using latest Jessie build and a USB Audio Device**

It appears that recent builds all come with ALSA's dmix plugin built-in. This allows you to share and output audio output stream

**Create New .asoundrc**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano .asoundrc
```

**Copy/Paste** this based on USB Audio Device is the second card in system

```
pcm.LineOut {
    type dmix # Kernel PCM
    ipc_key 1112233  # Any Unique Number Number
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0" # Card # of USB Audio from aplay -l
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 8192
        rate 48000
        #periods 128
     }
}

pcm.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
```

**Modify ALSA settings** to make the USB Audio device the default using

```
alsamixer
<F6>
Select the USB Sound Card
Change Inout to Line if you have a high end Audio device, otherwise leave as Mic
Modify volumes to 40-50%
```

On exit, **save settings**

```
alsactl store
```

**Start the stream** playback from Audio In direct to Audio Out (& will return to command line)

```
arecord -f dat | aplay -D "LineOut" &
<CR>
```

**Reduce volume of line input:**

```
 amixer set Line,0 0%
```

Use dmix shared pcm device to **insert wav file** previously recorded from line in:

```
aplay -D LineOut -R 48000 hiVol.wav
```

When it's all done **restore the volume** back to normal:

```
amixer set Line,0 50%
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`module-loopback`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index64h3) functionality of PulseAudio. First identify the names for your sound card's line in and speakers using `pactl list sources` and `pactl list sinks` respectively. Then create the loopback:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=src_name sink=sink_name
```

If your soundcard is detected with correct default source and sink, simply running `pactl load-module module-loopback` may be enough.

Once the loopback is created, the sink and source it uses can be modified with `pavucontrol`.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look and give that a try. It looks like the Python software does something similar in that when I start it up, it automatically starts the passthru and the speaker starts playing the audio coming thru the mp3 Player connected to line-in. Stops when I stop the process

Comment: I can do it directly using `arecord -f dat | aplay` and it never uses more than 3-4% cpu.