# How can I output my USB microphone through the jack port?

Tags: audio, raspbian-jessie

My Raspberry Pi 3 is going to be used like a music center, it will play various songs and videos but recently I want to implement a "voice amplifier" command or software, I tried to find on Google similar topics but only found related topics like streaming audio from one Pi to another or a baby monitor...

TL;DR-> Basically outputting anything that my microphone hears through jack port.

My setup is

- RPI 3B 1.2ghz w/ Raspbian Jessie OS March update
- Blue Snowball iCE USB microphone
- Old but awesome big Pioneer speakers (Connects through Jack)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to route audio directly from usb-audio line-in to same usb audio line-out?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56278/possible-to-route-audio-directly-from-usb-audio-line-in-to-same-usb-audio-line-o)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [alsaaudio](https://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/)

Here is an exemple(Not sure if it work):

```
import alsaaudio, audioop

micro = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE,card='hw:1,0')#Microphone
micro.setchannels(1)
micro.setrate(10) #10
micro.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S8)
micro.setperiodsize(32) # 32

output = alsaaudio.PCM(mode=alsaaudio.PCM_ASYNC , card='hw:1,0')#Speakers
output.setchannels(1)
output.setrate(100)
output.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S8)
output.setperiodsize(320)

while True:
    sample_length, sample = micro.read()
    sortie.write(sample)
```